# Run time addition of Spring MVC controller to existing spring MVC container

Tags: spring-mvc, architecture, module, osgi-bundle, spring-dm

I have a plugin kind of architecture and each plugins are webapps.
1. I wanted to develop each plugin as a spring MVC component(controller)
2. Then add them at run time while the spring container is still up and running.

Also these components can have dependency on each other.

I am looking into Spring DM and OSGI, but i'm not convinced with OSGI.

Can someone please help.

Comment: OSGI is probably a good bet. Check out https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded too

Comment: Thanks Neil, I looked into it. Gave me some ideas.